# sql script to export table's column data to another table's column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say , I have two table with same schema but different data .
`Table_A` and `Table_B` .

```
Table_A
--------
ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
-----------------------------------------------------
ID1                1                  AAA         BBB
ID1                2                  CCC         DDD
ID2                1                  EEE         FFF
ID2                2                  GGG         HHH
```

-

```
Table_B
--------
ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
-----------------------------------------------------
ID1                1                  AAA_1       BBB_1
ID1                2                  CCC_1       DDD_1
ID2                1                  EEE_1       FFF_1
ID2                2                  GGG_1       HHH_1
```

I want to export(overwrite) `Table_B column3` data to `Table_A column3` , where `ID` and `Number` Columns data are equal .
After executing of script , Table_A's data should be ,

```
 Table_A
    --------
    ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
    -----------------------------------------------------
    ID1                1                  AAA_1        BBB
    ID1                2                  CCC_1        DDD
    ID2                1                  EEE_1        FFF
    ID2                2                  GGG_1        HHH
```

How can I make this using sql script only ?
I use MS SQL-Server 2008 R2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update with a simple join will work.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A
    (ID varchar(3) not null, Number int not null, Column3 varchar(5), Column4 varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table_A
    (ID, Number, Column3, Column4)
VALUES
    ('ID1', 1, 'AAA', 'BBB'),
    ('ID1', 2, 'CCC', 'DDD'),
    ('ID2', 1, 'EEE', 'FFF'),
    ('ID2', 2, 'GGG', 'HHH')
;



CREATE TABLE Table_B
    (ID varchar(3) not null, Number int not null, Column3 varchar(5), Column4 varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table_B
    (ID, Number, Column3, Column4)
VALUES
    ('ID1', 1, 'AAA_1', 'BBB_1'),
    ('ID1', 2, 'CCC_1', 'DDD_1'),
    ('ID2', 1, 'EEE_1', 'FFF_1'),
    ('ID2', 2, 'GGG_1', 'HHH_1')
;

alter table Table_A 
add constraint pk_ID_NUM_A PRIMARY KEY (ID, Number)
go
alter table Table_B 
add constraint pk_ID_NUM_B PRIMARY KEY (ID, Number)

select * from Table_A
select * from Table_B
```

[image]

Now run the update :

```
update Table_A
set Table_A.Column3 = Table_B.Column3
from Table_A inner join Table_B
on Table_A.ID = Table_B.ID
and Table_A.Number=Table_B.Number
```

Below is the expected result that you want :

```
select * from Table_A
select * from Table_B
```

[image]